# Convert Date to interval string oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals

I have the following validation:

```
DATE1 + INTERVAL to_char(DATE2, 'HH24:MI:SS') HOUR TO SECOND > DATE3;
```

But it keeps me saying that the operator is not valid. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the time part from `DATE2` and add it to `DATE1`? I'm afraid that Oracle doesn't recognize `TO_CHAR(date2...)` as an `INTERVAL` literal even though it appears to be in the correct format. I would try this instead (good old-fashioned Oracle date arithmetic):

```
date1 + ( date2 - TRUNC(date2) ) > date3;
```

You could also do the following:

```
 date1 + TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || TO_CHAR(date2, 'HH24:MI:SS')) > date3;
```

where `date2` is converted to a `DAY TO SECOND` `INTERVAL` (I'm using `0` for the number of days since you want only the time part).